# Partition by most recent data - Sql Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, data-partitioning

how can I partition my table into two. One with latest one month data and the rest into another partition? I am using SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition.

Comment: Based on the linked question above: you can do this, but it isn't going to be useful because SQL Server will not move existing data to another partition.

Comment: SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition does not support partitioning.